# Convert a python list to an SQL composite type array to pass as parameter to a postgreSQL function

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have following composite type in postgreSQL:

```
 Composite type "public.type_data"
   Column    |  Type   | Modifiers 
-------------+---------+-----------
 series_id   | text    | 
 data_date   | date    | 
 data_value  | numeric | 
 data_source | text    |
```

that I use to pass as argument `VARIADIC input_array type_data[]` to a function in postgreSQL.   I also have the following list in python:

```
list = [['BRLUSD', '2021-02-26', 5.5302, 'gen'], ['BRLUSD', '2021-02-25',  5.46, 'gen']]
```

that I want to pass as argument to my function. I use `query = cur.mogrify("SELECT * FROM data_update(%s::type_data);", (list))` to get the query string but it returns the following error:

```
query = cur.mogrify("SELECT * FROM data_update(%s::type_data);", (list) )
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

What am I missing. Is there a better way to pass a list as an array argument for a postgreSQL function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast to an array of `type_data` rather than the type `type_data`  Also, the inner lists should be tuples: psycopg2 treats lists as arrays.

The [register_composite](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#composite-types-casting) function may be useful if you need to work with composite types returned by Postgresql in Python code.

```py
import psycopg2


with psycopg2.connect(database="test") as conn:
    cur = conn.cursor()

    cur.execute("""DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS get_my_values""")
    cur.execute("""DROP TYPE IF EXISTS my_type""")
    conn.commit()

    cur.execute(
        """CREATE TYPE my_type AS (series_id text, data_date date, data_value numeric, data_source text)"""
    )

    cur.execute(
        """CREATE FUNCTION get_my_values(my_type[]) RETURNS numeric AS $$
             SELECT $1[1].data_value AS dv
           $$ LANGUAGE SQL;"""
    )

    conn.commit()

    data = [
        (
            "BRLUSD",
            "2021-02-26",
            5.5302,
            "gen",
        ),
        (
            "BRLUSD",
            "2021-02-25",
            5.46,
            "gen",
        ),
    ]

    cur.execute("""SELECT get_my_values(%s::my_type[])""", (data,))

    (result,) = cur.fetchone()
    print(result)
```

Comment: Thank you. Two questions: I converted the list to tuples using `data = tuple(zip(list[0],list[1],list[2], list[3]))` where `list = [['BRLUSD', 'BRLUSD'], ['2021-02-26', '2021-02-25'] , [5.5302, 5.46 ], ['gen', 'gen']]` and returns ouput **(('BRLUSD', '2021-02-26', 5.5302, 'gen'), ('BRLUSD', '2021-02-25', 5.46, 'gen'))
** with class **<class 'tuple'>**, but when I run `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data_update(%s::my_type[]);", (data,) )` I get error **psycopg2.errors.CannotCoerce: cannot cast type record to my_type[]
LINE 1: ...02, 'gen'), ('BRLUSD', '2021-02-25', 5.46, 'gen'))::my_type[...**

Comment: If I create data with `data= [('BRLUSD', '2021-02-26', 5.5302, 'gen'), ('BRLUSD', '2021-02-25', 5.46, 'gen')]` it returns class
**<class 'list'>**
but `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data_update(%s::my_type[]);", (data,) )` returns 
**psycopg2.errors.UndefinedFunction: function data_update(my_type[]) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT * FROM data_update(ARRAY[('BRLUSD', '2021-02-26', 5.5...
                      ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.**

Comment: I am calling a function, that's why there is no `WHERE`, the only way I was able to make it work is passing the array of values with the tuple data structure as string and callling `"SELECT * FROM data_update('" + array_with_string_values + "' );"`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how I missed that you were using a Postgres function.  I've amended the answer.  If it still doesn't work perhaps you could add your function's signature to the question.